# Routing subdomains to certain applications in Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I've been trying out Application Gateway, and have managed to get to the point where hosting 2 applications in different pools, albeit with same port is possible using the "host" header to choose where i intended to be directed.

However, what i actually intended to do was route subdomains to certain applications.
For example, my application gateway is "app-gw.example.com", and i have 2 Azure Functions sat behind that, for simplicity, func1.example.com and func2.example.com. (They actually have distinct domains themselves, not subdomains).
I would like to route "func1.app-gw.example.com"'s traffic to func1.example.com, and "func2.app-gw.example.com" to "func2.example.com".

However, i can't seem to figure this out. Can someone explain how this can be done?
I've had also some success hosting on different ports and using the listener + routes to direct to each individual site, but they should rather be on the same port, which rules this out.

I've also tried messing with URL Rewrites, but wasn't able to get something useful from that either.

EDIT: I think maybe i'm missing something here. Perhaps i need something that points the domain names to the application gateway, and then route on that? For example:
Site 1, reachable at func1.example.com may have an entry called "func1-gw.example.com", which actually just points to the application gateway, however, the application gateway now knows that it's really supposed to be going to "func1"?
Sounds like a DNS record pointing to the gateway may work, but then i wonder how to do the routing, hmm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already aware of [Application Gateway multiple site hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/multiple-site-overview), you can enhance the Application Gateway to route the traffic based on the URLs.

Below references might help you configure the URL based routing.

1. [URL Path Based Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/url-route-overview)
2. [Application Gateway redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-overview)
3. [Configure URL redirection on an application gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-url-redirect-powershell)

Comment: Again: please refrain from posting link-only answers.